# wcf service showing error when deployed on server

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a wcf service which is running fine on my localhost, now the issue is that when I try to deploy it on server it gives me the following error:

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the
>   endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpBinding. Registered base
>   address schemes are [].

```
[InvalidOperationException: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [].]
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.MakeAbsoluteUri(Uri relativeOrAbsoluteUri, Binding binding, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +16604769
   System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadServiceDescription(ServiceHostBase host, ServiceDescription description, ServiceElement serviceElement, Action`1 addBaseAddress) +1082
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.ApplyConfiguration() +156
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses) +215
   System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost..ctor(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +475
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses) +43
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +530
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1413
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +50
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1172

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/HighriseSite/appservices.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding MetadataExchangeHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are []..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +901424
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +178638
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.OnAsyncEventCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +107
```

Web-service on server is configured like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
      <add prefix="http://49.50.72.21/HighriseSite/"/>
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="AppServicesBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="AppServicesBehavior" name="AppServices">
      <endpoint address="http://49.50.72.21/HighriseSite/AppServices.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IAppServices" behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior">
        <identity>
          <dns value="http://49.50.72.21/"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

While as webservice on my local host is configured like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
      <add prefix="http://localhost:7378/HighriseeSite/"/>
    </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
  </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="AppServicesBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="JsonBehavior">
        <webHttp/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="AppServicesBehavior" name="AppServices">
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:7378/HighriseeSite/AppServices.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IAppServices" behaviorConfiguration="JsonBehavior">
        <identity>
          <dns value="http://localhost:7378/"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I am not able to figure out why it is running smoothly on localhost but shows error on server.

Comment: where is the port number ?, the port number needs to be a part of the endpoint address.

Comment: Used port no like this http://49.50.72.21:80 in web.config but same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is that you're exposing an endpoint over webHttpBinding but specifying you want a WSDL definition exposed also.

Metadata endpoints are used for endpoints exposed over SOAP bindings, like basicHttpBinding or wcHttpBinding. So if you want to use webHttpBinding you cannot have a mex binding defined.